# Trouble after adding an NSArray of images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nsarray

I'm having a little bit of a problem with my app, being new to this sort of thing its a little hard for me to figure out what's going on.

The errors i'm having are as followed

- Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=exc_I386_GPFLT)
- Implicit conversion loses integer precision: ‘NSUInterger’ (aka unsigned long’) to ‘u_int32’ (aka ‘unsigned int’)  **SOLVED*

the first one doesn't show as a red or yellow error, its just greed text under part of my code that shows below in 'figure 1'

the second part is a yellow error in the the array for selecting a random image to display in the `UIImageView` (Figure 2)

**Figure 1**

```
 NSArray *imageNameArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"toppipestyleone.png", "toppipestyletwo.png", "toppipestylethree.png", "toppipestylefour.png", "toppipestylefive.png", nil];
```

this is inside my method for placing the `UIImageView` i also have code in this method that tells the `UIImageView` to scroll from the right to left of the screen, i will post my entire method in "Figure 3"

**Figure 2**

```
PipeTop.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageNameArray objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform([imageNameArray count])]];
```

**Figure 3**

```
-(void)PlacePipe{



    NSArray *imageNameArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"toppipestyleone.png", "toppipestyletwo.png", "toppipestylethree.png", "toppipestylefour.png", "toppipestylefive.png", nil];

    PipeTop.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageNameArray objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform([imageNameArray count])]];


    RandomTopPipePosition = arc4random() %350;
    RandomTopPipePosition = RandomTopPipePosition - 228;
    RandomBottomPipePosition = RandomTopPipePosition + 660;

    PipeTop.center = CGPointMake(340-10, RandomTopPipePosition);
    randomImagebottom.center = CGPointMake(340-10, RandomBottomPipePosition);


}
```

I think the second error has something to do with 32 and 64bit devices but I can't find an actual fix for my exact problem most of the problems I have read about people are using `NSZombies`? I'm not too sure what that it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1

!real error: from kirsteins:
"Only the first array object is NSString @"toppipestyleone.png", all other are c string literals. You should add @ before them to make the NSString literals."

he/she delete their answer, though it was right...

```
NSArray *imageNameArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"toppipestyleone.png", @"toppipestyletwo.png", @"toppipestylethree.png", @"toppipestylefour.png", @"toppipestylefive.png", nil];
```

## 2

arrays are zero based and count-1 is the last index. about the warning. cast it:

so:

```
NSUInteger index = (NSUInteger)arc4random_uniform((int)[imageNameArray count]-1);
PipeTop.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageNameArray objectAtIndex:index]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think while choosing random the count goes high from your array count use this to get random index between the array count..

```
int r = arc4random() % [yourArray count];
   if(r<[yourArray count])
    obj=[yourArray objectAtIndex:r];
   else
       {
     //error message
        }
```

Comment: you are right but why not just tell arc4random_uniform that max is count-1?